# Why does nested function playing gif in tkinter starts playing faster with each call?

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, gif

I am trying to play two different gif files in tkinter based on user input. The function runs on a thread. However with each input the gif starts playing faster than the previous one. Here is the code:

```
 def threaded_function():
    print ("thread running")
    root=tk.Tk()                   # initiate window
    lbl = ImageLabel(root)         # a new class ImageLabel defined to play gif
    lbl.pack()                     # align labels in main window
    def ask_for_userinput():
        user_input = input("Give me your command! Just type \"exit\" to close: ")

        if (user_input == "1"):
            lbl.load('giphy.gif')
            root.after(5, ask_for_userinput)
        else:
            lbl.load('giphy3.gif')
            root.after(5, ask_for_userinput)

    root.after(5, ask_for_userinput)    
    root.mainloop()
```

I think that somehow, each nested call of *ask_for_userinput()* runs faster than the previous one.
To take a look at how ImageLabel is implemented:

```
class ImageLabel(tk.Label):
    """a label that displays images, and plays them if they are gifs"""
    def load(self, im):
        self.unload()
        if isinstance(im, str):
            im = Image.open(im)
        # self.unload()
        self.loc = 0
        self.frames = []

        try:
            self.frames=[]
            for i in count(1):
                self.frames.append(ImageTk.PhotoImage(im.copy()))
                im.seek(i)
        except EOFError:
            pass

        try:
            self.delay = im.info['duration']
        except:
            self.delay = 100

        if len(self.frames) == 1:
            self.config(image=self.frames[0])
        else:
            self.next_frame()

    def unload(self):
        self.config(image=None)
        self.frames = None

    def next_frame(self):
        if self.frames:
            self.loc += 1
            self.loc %= len(self.frames)
            self.config(image=self.frames[self.loc])
            self.after(self.delay, self.next_frame)
```

**Update:
Here is the solution**
Changing ImageLabel class worked:

```
class ImageLabel(tk.Label):
    """a label that displays images, and plays them if they are gifs"""
    def load(self, im):
        if not hasattr(self, 'job'):
            self.job = None
        self.unload()
        if isinstance(im, str):
            im = Image.open(im)
        # self.unload()
        self.loc = 0
        self.frames = []
        try:
            self.frames=[]
            for i in count(1):
                self.frames.append(ImageTk.PhotoImage(im.copy()))
                im.seek(i)
        except EOFError:
            pass

        try:
            self.delay = im.info['duration']
        except:
            self.delay = 100

        if len(self.frames) == 1:
            self.config(image=self.frames[0])
        else:
            self.next_frame()

    def unload(self):
        if self.job is not None:
            self.after_cancel(self.job)
            self.job = None
        self.config(image=None)
        self.frames = None

    def next_frame(self):
        if self.frames:
            self.loc += 1
            self.loc %= len(self.frames)
            self.config(image=self.frames[self.loc])
            self.job = self.after(self.delay, self.next_frame)
```

Comment: It's because you never cancel any pending "after" jobs, you just keep adding more.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That worked